# pattern search on vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, pattern-matching

is there any better and faster way of achieving the below ? 
Basically , I am looking(searching) for a pattern in a Data frame.

The below works for me. But I can't scale it. Time complexity is really my concern.

```
 searchPattern <- function(ls, pattern){
    sapply(ls, function(x) {
    tmp <- all(table(x)[names(table(pattern))]>=table(pattern))
    ifelse(is.na(tmp),FALSE,tmp)
     })
    }

 pattern <- c(5,1)
 df <- list(1,c(1,7,4,5),c(6,5,1,1),5:10,c(5,5,1,1))
 df
 searchPattern(df,pattern)
```

The results is a logical vector:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

The pattern in this example is just `c(5,1)`, but it is looped to get different patterns like `1,c(1,7,4,5),c(6,5,1,1),5:10,c(5,5,1,1)`

Based on this I am carrying out other transformation later. What is the ideal and faster way to do it? 
any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like `vapply(df, function(x) length(intersect(x, pattern)) == length(pattern), logical(1L))`.

Comment: Use the `map` function from the `purrr` package for efficiency: `map(df, function(x) length(intersect(pattern, x)) == length(pattern))`. You can use the base `Map` too: `Map(function(x) length(intersect(pattern, x)) == length(pattern), df)`.

Comment: Thx . But the function should return `[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE` for `pattern <- c(5,1,1)` and not `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: So, what other rules do we need to be aware of? All positive integers?

Comment: @RoshanA try `map(df, function(x) sum(x %in% pattern) >= length(pattern))`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 thank you. I was looking for something similar to @Abdou has suggested. I tweaked it so i get a vector.
`vapply(df, function(x) sum(x %in% pattern) >= length(pattern), logical(1L))`. Thanks again guys. This is faster than my approach

Comment: you could consider using library(foreach). It allows for parallel execution.

Comment: @RoshanA, your solution is incorrect. If you respond to my question about whether there are other constraints we should be aware of, I may have an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're dealing with positive integers. The solution you have come up with based on the comments is incorrect.

Example:

```
x <- c(5, 1, 1)
test <- list(c(1, 5, 1, 1), c(1, 5), c(5, 1, 1), c(6, 1, 6, 5, 1, 5), c(1, 1, 1))

rec <- function(ll, patt) vapply(ll, function(x) sum(x %in% patt) >= length(patt), logical(1L))

rec(test, x)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Here's a function that works (where "works" == "matches the output of your existing function"). It uses `tabulate` instead of `table`, which can be considerably faster.

```
sp <- function(ll, patt) {
  xt <- tabulate(patt)
  xu <- unique(patt)
  vapply(ll, function(z) all(tabulate(z, max(xu))[xu] >= xt[xu]), logical(1L))
}

sp(test, x)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Test it out on something larger:

```
set.seed(2)
y <- replicate(100, sample(8, sample(4:10, 1), TRUE), FALSE)
x <- c(5, 1, 1)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sp(y, x), searchPattern(y, x))
## Unit: microseconds
##                 expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
##             sp(y, x)   267.134   295.096   312.9538   311.1815   323.369   485.269   100
##  searchPattern(y, x) 24709.732 25218.143 26663.5091 25737.1475 28478.559 31324.695   100

identical(sp(y, x), searchPattern(y, x))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: you are absolutely  right. I dint give all the conditions it has to follow. Thax for taking the time out and putting it altogether. I would test this on large data and let you the performance